# Prevent unnecessary re-render of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lambda, closures

I have a PureComponent that renders another component and implements its `onClick` callback:

```
class ColorPicker extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('ColorPicker being rendered');
    const fields = this.props.colors.map((color, idx) => {
      const fieldProps = {
        key: `${idx}`,
        color,
        /*onClick: () => { // PROBLEM HERE
          this.props.colorPicked(color);
        }*/
      };
      return <ColorField { ...fieldProps}/>;
    });
    return (
      <div className="bla-picker">
        <div>{`Refresh seed: ${this.props.seed}`}</div>
        {fields}
      < /div>
    );
  }
}
```

There is a small issue with this component: Whenever the `ColorPicker` is re-rendered, the nested `ColorField`s need to be re-rendered, too, because their `onClick` property changes each time. Using a lambda function will create a new instance of that function whenever the component is rendered.

I usually solve this by moving the implementation of `onClick` outside of the `render` method, like this: `onClick: this.handleClick`. However, I can't do this here, because the `onClick` handler needs to capture the `color` variable.

What's the best practice to solve this kind of problem?

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmpLvt6s/) to try it out; and as a snippet:

```js
class ColorField extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('ColorField being rendered');
    const divProps = {
      className: 'bla-field',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: this.props.color
      },
      onClick: this.props.onClick
    };
    return <div { ...divProps}/>;
  }
}
class ColorPicker extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('ColorPicker being rendered');
    const fields = this.props.colors.map((color, idx) => {
      const fieldProps = {
        key: `${idx}`,
        color,
        /*onClick: () => { // PROBLEM HERE
          this.props.colorPicked(color);
        }*/
      };
      return <ColorField { ...fieldProps}/>;
    });
    return (
      <div className="bla-picker">
        <div>{`Refresh seed: ${this.props.seed}`}</div>
        {fields}
      < /div>
    );
  }
}

class Layout extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props, ctx) {
    super(props, ctx);
    this.state = {
      seed: 1
    };
  }
  render() {
    const pickerProps = {
      colors: ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f'],
      colorPicked: (color) => {
        console.log(`Color picked: ${color}`);
      },
      seed: this.state.seed
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="bla-button"
          onClick = {this.btnClicked}
        >
          {'Click Me'}
        </div>
        <ColorPicker { ...pickerProps} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  btnClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ seed: this.state.seed + 1 });
  };
};

ReactDOM.render( <
  Layout / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.bla-button {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.bla-picker {}

.bla-field {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="react">
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

As long as `onClick` remains commented out, only `ColorPicker` is re-rendered when the seed changes (see output from `console.log`). As soon as `onClick` is put in, all the `ColorField`s are re-rendered, too.

Comment: For live examples (as I mentioned the last time you asked this question), please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), not off-site resources like jsFiddle. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: It's not the same question, because now I use PureComponent rather than SFCs. I know stackoverflow allows live examples, however, I found it tedious to try things out; you can't unless you press the answer button.

Comment: Your finding it tedious is no reason to hide the live example away off-site. If you think a fiddle is also useful, include it **as well**, not instead. The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot (and jsFiddle has been known to be down -- had trouble just last week, in fact), making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in your ColorField component like:

```
class ColorField extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.color !== nextProps.color;
  }

  render(){
    const { color, onClick } = this.props;
    console.log('Color re-rendered');
    return (
      <div 
        className="color"
        onClick={onClick}
        style={{ 
          backgroundColor: color,
          height: '50px',
          width: '50px',
        }} 
      />
    )
  }
}
```

[Example here](https://codepen.io/teimurjan/pen/Vddpzd?editors=1010)

Be attentive as in the first solution we can use just React.Component because we implement `shouldComponentUpdate` by ourselves.

Comment: The second solution has a problem. In my original code, ColorPicker passed the color up to the parent component, which is what a ColorPicker is supposed to do. You eliminated this, and now onColorClick doesn't need to access this.props. The solution doesn't work if the callback is put back in.

Comment: Just pass you onClick from the main parent through all the children without passing any argument to it. Then in ColorField pass the color. It must work

Comment: ColorField should not need to pass the color back, because from its point of view, it is simply clicked; there is only one color. ColorPicker, on the other hand, knows that there are other colors, so it wants to tell its caller which of them was picked.

Comment: It is your opinion about the architecture. I just tell you how to manage your problem technically in order to avoid least re-renders

Comment: Certainly. But it is a very common idiom to compose a complex problem into simpler ones; the simpler components should not know the details of their parents. ColorPicker may need to tell its parent even more details, things a ColorField should not need to know. The index of the color, for instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Otherwise, there is the first solution which is working :)

Comment: There is also the confusing text "I am new function on every render" in the second example. This is not true; its always the same function since you've moved it outside. So, maybe you just drop the second solution, and I mark it as the answer. :)